# configuring a MVC3 site on mod-mono, now getting exceptions while running code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, mod-mono

Let's see if anyone here can help with a problem deploying a MVC3 site on apache using mod_mono.

My mono installation is 3.10.1 (exactly the same thing happens on 3.10.0) and latest mod_mono and xsp. I installed mono from source that I got from a git branch.

Problem is an exception I get when trying to authenticate a user. The exception happens when I call Membership.Validate and is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Failed to map path '/'

 at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath (System.String virtualPath, System.String baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) [0x001a4] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs:1563 
  at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath (System.String virtualPath) [0x0000d] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs:1520 
  at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath (System.String virtualPath) [0x00042] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/HostingEnvironment.cs:156 
  at System.Web.Hosting.DefaultVirtualPathProvider.DirectoryExists (System.String virtualDir) [0x00016] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/DefaultVirtualPathProvider.cs:59 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.FindWebConfig (System.String path, System.Boolean& inAnotherApp) [0x0001a] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationManager.cs:592 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration (System.String path, System.String site, System.String locationSubPath, System.String server, System.String userName, System.String password, Boolean fweb) [0x00026] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationManager.cs:360 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x0000d] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationManager.cs:456 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path) [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationManager.cs:435 
  at System.Web.Security.SqliteMembershipProvider.Initialize (System.String name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config) [0x0028b] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/SqliteMembershipProvider.cs:143 
  at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider (System.Configuration.ProviderSettings providerSettings, System.Type providerType) [0x00069] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/ProvidersHelper.cs:61 
  at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders (System.Configuration.ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderCollection providers, System.Type providerType) [0x0003e] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/ProvidersHelper.cs:72 
  at System.Web.Security.Membership..cctor () [0x0001a] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/Membership.cs:107
```

I tried a site that uses a custom membership provider, and another site that uses default one, both display the same issue. 
I tried these on 2 different servers, on mono 3.10.1 and 3.10.0.

I configured the site using the automated configuration tool: http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/ and using the default configuration it gave as such:

```
  Alias /boacommander "/var/www/html/boacommander"
  MonoServerPath boacommander "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
  MonoDebug boacommander true
  MonoSetEnv boacommander MONO_IOMAP=all
  MonoApplications boacommander "/boacommander:/var/www/html/boacommander"
  <Location "/boacommander">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias boacommander
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  </Location>
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
  </IfModule>
```

The following dlls are copied along the site:

- EntityFramework.dll
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- MVC3.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.Services.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

The exception happens in System.Web, so if I copy a System.Web.dll along, I get this exception before even getting onto the logon page:

```
Could not find method 'Void SetHostingEnvironment()' in type 'System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost'
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x002fb] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/ApplicationHost.cs:241
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00048] in /usr/local/src/xsp/src/Mono.WebServer/VPathToHost.cs:143
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean v_quiet) [0x00277] in /usr/local/src/xsp/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:161
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00034] in /usr/local/src/xsp/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:58
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Could not find method 'Void SetHostingEnvironment()' in type 'System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost'

Server stack trace:
  at System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder.GetRealObject (StreamingContext context) [0x00215] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MemberInfoSerializationHolder.cs:158
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00133] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization/ObjectManager.cs:596
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00074] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization/ObjectManager.cs:85
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject (System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x0000f] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectReader.cs:141
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean readHeaders, System.Object& result, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x0004d] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectReader.cs:107
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x0007a] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:177
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:134
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.DeserializeCallData (System.Byte[] array) [0x0000f] in /usr/local/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting/RemotingServices.cs:794
  at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (object,byte[]&,byte[]&)
```

Damned if you do, damned if you don't, so what can I do to fix this problem?

EDIT with additional information: The same thing happens while using mono 3.12.0 (git branch)

Comment: System.Web is .NET-specific and you should not copy it over (mono has its own version)

Comment: Thank You, I'll keep using the mono version. Then I'll need to work on the "Failed to map path '/'" error, problem still persists.